# How to detect what is visible point of view

Tags: language-agnostic, collision-detection

I'm currently programming a maze game, and I'm trying to program limited point of view (I don't think that that is the term, but I'm drawing a blank).  My goal is to only reveal what is not hidden behind walls in the maze.

Some important facts:

1. My walls are not lines, they are blocks (which should make things easier).
2. The view is limited to a max of 5 squares away.
3. The squares have a size determined by the user

Here's my current idea:

1. Create a list of angles (maybe 15 degrees apart?)
2. For each of the angles, calculate point 1 square-distance away in each of the angles.
3. Add square on the point found to a set
4. If square is blocked, remove angle from list.

Will this work, or is there a better way to do limited point-of-view?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're asking -- are you asking about occlusion in 3D rendering of a first person maze game? If so, Wolfenstein 3D is a classic example of [raycasting](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html).

However, modern hardware is generally good enough to drown problems like this in fill rate -- naive rendering of 3D scenes with OpenGL or DirectX can just "do the right thing" with [Z-buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering).

If you're not worried about drawing but instead about collision detection, you can probably use raycasting for that as well. If you're not looking to implement your own complex stuff, you could use a  physics library like [Box2D](http://box2d.org/).

Comment: Heh, I already figured it out.  I won't use any graphical framework (except for Swing), so that's out.  My question was "If I am standing in position x,y (2D), how do I tell what is visible from my point, assuming I can only see 5 squares away.  My solution above solved it.